# Dual display works with LiveCD but not full install

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics

Reasonably new to Ubuntu desktop and I am having issues with an external display. I downloaded the 18.04 USB boot ISO. When I 'try Ubuntu' whatever settings it is using it picks up my external display.

However, when I do a full install, the display is not picked up.I even went into software updates and updated the drivers for my  NVIDIA GeForce GTX 960M 2G Graphics Card, still no second screen.

I'm assuming that somewhere there is a config file that is allowing the external screen to be picked up in LiveCD and also full Ubuntu. Would I need to look at these to see any issues. If so, anyone know where can they be found?

---

EDIT:

So, I have been doing some digging. I thought it might be a BIOS issue. So I went into the BIOS and looking through I noticed there was 2 boot options for Ubuntu, so I disabled one. For some reason that has fixed the issue, but now each time I boot up I get a boot menu displayed instead of loading Ubuntu by default. I could delete one in the BIOS but was wondering if there is another way to do it.